# Integral identity graphs -- smallest example

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

From [Paulus Graphs](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PaulusGraphs.html).

"The (25,2)-, (25,4)-, and (26,10)-Paulus graphs have the apparently rather unusual property of being both [integral graphs](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegralGraph.html) (or asymmetric) and [identity graphs](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IdentityGraph.html) (a graph spectrum consisting entirely of integers)."

I once quietly [conjectured this was impossible](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/4oyvo8/conjectures_where_the_proof_was_contrary_to/), but I was proven wrong.  Very wrong.  Eric Weisstein was amused enough by my reaction that he added the above quote.

Is there a smaller counterexample?

Comment: Very neat question - what is known about the relationship between the automorphism group of a graph and its spectrum? I would appreciate any links!

Comment: These graphs are strongly regular, and for strongly regular graphs this combination of properties is probably the norm.

Comment: Someone swapped the parenthetical definitions of identity and integral!

Comment: There is the trivial answer of the one-vertex zero-edge graph...