# Known results on the relationship between automorphisms and spectrum of a graph?

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, algebraic-combinatorics

I recently saw [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1834586/integral-identity-graphs-smallest-example) post from Ed Pegg on Math Stack Exchange about integral graphs with trivial automorphism groups. I am interested in trying to construct smaller such graphs - at the very least, I would like to learn about the machinery involved. What are some known results on the relationship between the automorphisms of a graph and the spectrum of the graph? I am sure there are many known results but I haven't found a good online resource yet. I wouldd appreciate any explanations and or references. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chan and Godsil have an excellent survey [here](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~cgodsil/pdfs/mont.pdf). They include an exposition on equitable partitions, which was the example that immediately came to mind. Cvetkovic, Rowlinson, and Simic also treat equitable partitions in their London Mathematical Society text on spectral graph theory.

Comment: Thanks for these great references - I skimmed through the survey of Chan and Godsil and it seems to be exactly what I was looking for! I'll leave this question open for a little while longer in case anyone has other references of explanations.